# Translate calendar view in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions, localisation

I have installed the Events Calendar extension [magento connect](http://magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/events-calendar-3464.html) on my shop. 
The language set on the shop is cyrillic (Macedonian) so the calendar view(months, days of the week) is showing symbols text. Does somebody know how to translate the calendar to the language?

Comment: Please provide the name of the extension you've installed

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/events-calendar-3464.html

Comment: Please update your answer with a link to the extension for reference

Comment: just to add that i didn't install through magento connect, but it is the same extension..Thanks

Comment: are you running the shop on linux or windows?

Comment: ..running on linux

Comment: Did you manage to get any further on this issue? @Petar just posted a comment with some nice info

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the extension but after downloading it and poking around a little I ended up in this class `MathieuF_EventsCalendar_Block_Events`.

The first interesting line of code is on line 106

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code'));
```

The reason why this is interesting is because the method that is called from this function `generate_calendar()` uses the `gmstrftime` to output the day names.

the setLocale uses the code set by you in the backend which should be `mk_MK`. My best guess is that something goes wrong when the `setlocale` is executed. Either the `mk_MK` code is wrong or unrecognized on your server or the language pack is not installed.

If you have access to SSH please run `locale -a` to see if the language pack is installed. If not contact your hosting provider.

Comment: yes mk language pack is installed..Thank you very much

Comment: Having symbols may mean that mk_MK is specific encoding like Windows CP 1251 and not UTF-8 which is magento encoding

Comment: @PetarDzhambazov good one, would `htmlentities` work here?

Comment: @SanderMangel I don't think `htmlentities` will help at all. The way this module approaches localization is too dependent on system environment. I believe that system settings being non reliable is the reason why Zend shipped such extensive localization with its components.Including Macedonian date localization in utf-8. So solution would be to iconv the strings or modify the module to use Magento locale.

Comment: Reference for OP; iconv is http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php